# Can't install flash on IE8

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, flash

I have a PC in a classroom attached to a projector.  Sometimes a teacher will want to show a youtube video or other flash content to their class.  The PC has not really been used all summer.

Now as the semester starts I get a report that flash is not installed on the machine.  I go to check it out, and not only is flash not installed in IE8, but it will not install.  When you try to install it, IE has to close the tab after two attempts.

I have tried removing and re-installing Internet Explorer, resetting all the security and privacy options to defaults, and I've also done a system restore going back a couple weeks with no luck.  Flash works fine in firefox on the machine, but that's really a kludge - not all the teachers will want to do that.

Any ideas for how to fix this?

Comment: Is this a 64-bit machine?

Comment: No, it's not 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

I work in a school system also, not a teacher though.

I suggest you get with your tech., as sometimes I am blocked from updating Flash, QuickTime, etc. due to permission policies. Whenever I get with the tech. they sign in as administrator and handle it.

Comment: Why did you make this a Community Wiki answer?

Comment: I _am_ the tech, and was signed in as an administrator during the re-install.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing Flash from the standalone installer?  Without being registered with Adobe to download the redistributable installer it's annoying to get to, but it can be done by going to the Flash download page at the Adobe site *in FireFox or other non IE browser* then following the "Other operating system or browser" link.  From there select XP/IE and it'll let you actually download the file so you can try it without IE open.

Edit: Or I can just put the [link](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/thankyou/?installer=Flash_Player_10.1_for_Windows_Internet_Explorer&i=McAfee_Security_Scan_Plus) to it here.